# Win8 App - Issues connecting to domain network server in Release Build

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a LOB app I am working on and having issues with network access.

The app uses OAuth style authentication and I have a custom Identity/Authorization server that the app connects to for authorization. That authorization server is on the local network (also accessible outside) and during early development I realized I had to set "Internet (Client & Server)" for it to be able to connect to the OAuth server, and was fine since.

Now a bit farther along and side loading it to test machines, and now can't get the domained machines to connect to the server if it is on the domain network (works just fine if I connect to a hotspot first).

Is there a special setting I am missing?

I also have "Private Networks (Client & Server)" Capability set as well

full list from manifest

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
 </Capabilities>
```

**UPDATE**

I added the following registry setting:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\authhost.exe\EnablePrivateNetwork = 00000001

found here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh750287.aspx

and that fixed it.It seems to me that it shouldn't take that to fix it, but seeing how its a LOB app, it can be taken care of.

Comment: I have tried adding a webview to the app, and navigate to the authentication page the WebAuthentication Broker uses, and the page comes up just fine in the webview, but not for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `<Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />`, although I doubt it will make any difference unless the server requires some kind of additional authentication for computers connecting from within the domain.

- What error are you getting when the app can't connect to the server?
- Can the test machines access that server from outside your app (i.e. it responds to e.g. ping)? If not, it's not a capabilities problem.

Comment: in the WebAuth event log I get an error entry with code 1050 the url that the web authentication broker uses, then a Verbose entry with: "AuthHost disallowed Url Action: 0x2301". I have dealt with this kind of error before, but that was before I had a correct ssl, or the Intranet capability set. The url that the app uses is browseable in metro IE, after I enable access to the private network.